# Passing context in iOS to use Core Data with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, managedobjectcontext

I'm having some problems in passing context from the app delegate to the view controller.
I've found many tutorials on the internet, and all suggest to use the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to create the view controller, set the context property and push it.
My problem is that I want to use storyboard, and the view controller is created and pushed within it, and not in the app delegate.

I've tried to do this in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//instantiate local context
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (!context)
{
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Error: Context is null");
}

//reference the view controller
helloCoreDataViewController1_001 *rootViewController = [helloCoreDataViewController1_001 alloc];

// Pass the managed object context to the view controller
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;

return YES;
}
```

and this in my view controller:

```
@implementation helloCoreDataViewController1_001

@synthesize name, address, phone, status, managedObjectContext;
//....

- (IBAction)saveContact
{
NSLog(@"name: %@",self.name.text);
NSLog(@"address: %@",self.address.text);
NSLog(@"phone: %@",self.phone.text); 

//Save the new instance of the contact entity
Contact *contact = (Contact *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[contact setContactName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name.text]];
[contact setValue:self.address.text forKey:@"address"];
[contact setContactPhone:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.phone.text]];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.description);
    self.status.text = @"Error: contact NOT saved";
}
else
    self.status.text = @"Contact saved";
}
```

When I debug, I can see that in the app delegate, the context is populated correctly, and also the property in the view controller is ok.
But when my `saveContact` method is invoked, the context is empty.

Do you have any suggestions about this? How can I pass the context to the view controller with storyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the Storyboard's rootviewcontroller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions by accessing

```
self.window.rootViewController
```

instead of allocing a new one.

So those two lines in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions should look like this:

```
helloCoreDataViewController1_001 *rootViewController = (helloCoreDataViewController1_001 *)self.window.rootViewController;
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing your managed obeject context to the view controller try to get it on the view controller from the appDelegate:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }
if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    }... //finish your fetch request of course...
}
```

With me it worked beautifully

Comment: This makes your class hierarchy very rigid, your view controller now must know about the app delegate and is dependent on it. I personally prefer to have a property on my view controller that I assign when creating the view.

Comment: @Chris you're right. This is just another method. I figured to use this in one of my apps that has a different context. This is just another option then...